# No logro hacer consulta con la base de datos por ID

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Logro hacer la consulta de la API pero cuando intento hacer la consulta a la base de datos me genera error
`Connection was refused by the server`

```
const getVideoGameById = async (id, source) => {
    const videogames =
        source === "bdd"
            ? await videogames.findByPk(id)
            : (await axios.get(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games/${id}?key=4be2ed928e1d42388d5f7aac8db2b987`)).data;

    return videogames;
};


const getVideoGamesHandler = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const source = isNaN(id) ? "bdd" : "api"
    try {
        const videogames = await getVideoGameById(id, source);
        res.status(201).json(videogames);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: error.message });
    }
};
```

Comment: Checa la conexión a la base de datos, trata de traer todos los datos de regreso (podrías hacer un simple GET que te traiga todos los elementos de la BD)